# Handling generic configuration file in c#

Tags: c#, configuration, app-config, application-settings, appsettings

i documented myself but couldn't found or understood how can i do what i want to achieve.

here is the thing :

- I cannot use registry (not sure i have rights on client computer)
- it need to be generic and transparent (code-side)

i have configuration settings in a project folder, let's says :

- Solution

  - project1

    - many code folder..
    - Settings

      - UserLevel

        - FirstEnv.settings
        - SecondEnv.settings
      - ApplicationLevel

        - FirstEnv.settings
        - SecondEnv.settings
  - project2

now I have a SettingFactory which (should) instantiate (or a least, assign value) in *.settings to my applicationSettings
i want to have something like :

```
public static void LoadSetting()
    {

        var env = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["environnement"];
        switch (env)
        {
            case "env1":                    ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration("Setting/AppLevel/firstEnv.settings");
                break;
            case "env2":                    ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration("Setting/AppLevel/secondEnv.settings");
                break;
            default :                    ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration("Setting/AppLevel/secondEnv.settings");
                break;
        }
    }
```

and a '(key,value)' in app.config

```
<applicationSettings>
  <add name="environnement" value="env1"/>
</applicationSettings>
```

So in my code, when i need to use settings i can simply refer to

```
ConfigurationManager.appsettings["targetURI"]
```

and when i want to switch 'environnement'

```
ConfigurationManager.appsettings["environnement"] = "env2";
SettingsFactory.LoadSettings();
```

Any advice on how to do this or any design pattern improvement ?

Moreover, i separate AppLevel settings and Userlevel settings, but it's kinda nothing more than a pair of (key,value). But easier for dev to work with. This way, i can modify environnement with ease by Code ( 2lines) or by editing app.config

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create your own class to store the settings that will be unique to each environment and then serialize/deserialize them to their own files using XmlSerialier.

Here's a really simple example of how XmlSerializer is used.

http://tech.pro/tutorial/798/csharp-tutorial-xml-serialization

```
static List<YourSettingsClass> DeserializeFromXML(string path)
{
    XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<YourSettingsClass>));
    TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(path);
    List<YourSettingsClass> settings;
    settings = (List<YourSettingsClass>)deserializer.Deserialize(textReader);
    textReader.Close();

    return settings;
}
```

Then store the path to your various environment settings files in your app.config.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="env1" value="C:\temp\env1-settings.xml"/>
    <add key="env2" value="C:\temp\env2-settings.xml"/>
</appSettings>
```

Load them with something like this:

```
List<YourSettingsClass> envSettings = DeserializeFromXML(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["env2"]);
```

Comment: so i need to handle encrypted section by hands etc.. ?

Comment: If you are wanting the content of the settings to be encrypted then yes. Check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/965188/1706610